# Stop radio after call

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm making an iphone Live radio application. My application is working fine in background mode. But, if the phone rings when radio app is playing in background mode, my radio stops.

```
MP AVAudioSessionDelegateMediaPlayerOnly end interruption. Interruptor <Phone> category <completed> resumable <0>,  _state = 6
2013-01-02 10:26:24.487 Radio99[2527:707] MP endInterruptionFromInterruptor :: resuming playback at 1.000000
```

Comment: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents]; 
After adding this line it's working on iphone 4 but it's still not working in iphone 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use only `AudioStreamer`. (Never use `AVAudioPlayer` or `MPMoviePlayerController` it's not play radio after call).

```
NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://y1.eoews.com/assets/ringtones/2012/5/18/34049/oiuxsvnbtxks7a0tg6xpdo66exdhi8h0bplp7twp.mp3"];
AudioStreamer *tempStreamer = [[AudioStreamer alloc] initWithURL:url];
self.streamer = tempStreamer;
[tempStreamer release]; [streamer start];
```

Add this code in background

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
   {

    CTCallCenter *_center = [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];

    _center.callEventHandler = ^(CTCall *call) 
        {

        if ([call.callState isEqualToString:CTCallStateIncoming]) 
            {   
                NSLog(@"Pause");
                [streamPlayer pause];
            }

        if ([call.callState isEqualToString:CTCallStateDisconnected]) 
            {
            NSLog(@"call:%@", call.callState);
            NSLog(@"Play");
            [streamPlayer start];
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
            [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];

Add above line and radio work perfect!!!!